# Use site:mysite.com search without adding impressions to Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, impressions

Is there a way to conduct a site:mysite.com search without it adding impressions to the Search Console > Search Analytics report?

When I do this search it adds a spike to the impressions contaminating the real number.

Is there a way to search when testing where a single page ranks, without adding it as an impression?

I found an old article (https://moz.com/ugc/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-google-search-parameters) listing search query params, one of which was &adtest=off which I hoped might do what I was looking for. But no.

I've tried a private browsing window... and no.

---

Edit: Since Google changed the title of Webmaster Tools there are now two things:

1) Google Analytics > Aquisition > Search Console > Queries

2) Search Console > Search Traffic > Search Analytics > Pages/Queries/etc.,

I'm asking about 2).

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude site operator queries in the performance report with filters in GSC.

1. Navigate to GSC > Performance > Queries
2. Add new query filter
3. Exclude queries containing "site:"

You can see clicks, impressions, CTR, and average position of an individual page by adding a page filter for "URL is exactly". The results show only that page's performance minus site operator queries.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent internal traffic from affecting your data, you can use a filter to filter out traffic by IP address.

You can find the public IP address you are currently using by searching "what is my ip address" .

**To create an IP address filter:**

1. Follow the instructions to [create a new filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823) for your view.
2. Leave the Filter Type as  Predefined.
3. Click the Select filter type drop-down menu and select Exclude.
4. Click the Select source or destination drop-down menu and select traffic from the IP addresses.
5. Click the Select expression drop-down menu and select the appropriate expression.
6. Enter the IP address or a regular expression.

Comment: How is a Google Analytics filter going to help with Search Console impressions?

Comment: Hi, Stephen. If I am not misunderstanding this... The Search Console reports in Analytics use four metrics specific to Google Web Search data: impressions, clicks, average position and CTR. Adding an IP filter in turn excludes that info in GA when coming from the excluded IP or IP range.

Comment: That data is imported from search console where the anylitics filters can't change it.  Anyway, he is asking about how to prevent the data from appearing in search console to begin with, so Google Analytics has nothing to do with it. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6155685?hl=en

Comment: hmm I could be wrong, but my understanding is he wants to search and see what shows up in search but not affect the fake impression numbers it generates in his GA report. Which is why a filter in GA can disclude this info in his GA report. But then again it is real early or late whichever... sleep time :P

Comment: I'm afraid Stephen has the correct understanding of what I'm asking. I'll amend the question to make this really clear. Thanks for trying though, it is appreciated - I have learned something:- I'm already excluded from GA... though I didn't realise this was a reason why the number of impressions can be lower in there vs Webmaster Tools/Search Console. (Google has confused things since it changed the terminology).