# Is my personal search considered in the Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have my website added to Google search console and it shows me the search terms that made my site appear in the search results.

When I perform a search on google, during being logged in with the same account that holds the Google Search Console, are my search results reflected in the Search Analytics? I dont want my own search terms occur in the Search Analytics, because it would bias the results (when having relatively few organic search traffic).

Additionally, if I register a custom search, are these searches tracked in the Search Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are my search results reflected in the Search Analytics?

**Yes** in Search Console

**No** in Google Analytics > Aquisition > Search Console. (This needs confirmation)

This is also the answer for a custom search (Not 100% sure I've understood you here though).

Test it out if you want to see for yourself. Find a really distinctive phrase on one of your webpages that would be highly unlikely to be used to search with by anyone else. Use it. Check your page is listed, so the search was successful. Then wait a couple of days (Google console is at least 2 days behind). Check for your very distinctive term. It is possible GA won't show it, thinking it's an 'infrequent' term, but it's worth a punt.

Of course, if you have a whole heap of privacy settings on, then the term won't appear. The impression will be there, but not the term.

An alternative test would be to search for a page you know gets hardly any impressions - if you have a page like that.

---

My own question is related: [Use site:mysite.com search without adding impressions to Google Search Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101193/use-sitemysite-com-search-without-adding-impressions-to-google-search-console)

Comment: Thank you for this information. I will have a try with a distinctive phrase and see, where and if it pops up. I will also try with the custom search. Once I have the results, I'll come back.

Comment: One possible exception is if you search Google on the network where your web server is. If the IP addresses are the same, the search may be ignored. Google does process some things differently if it appears to come from the web server IP address. Since most sites are hosted, this would not apply. However, if you run your own network, then the exception may apply. Cheers!!

Comment: Another point, Doesn't GA get search data from the Search Console? If this is true, then the Search Console and GA should behave the same. Cheers!!

Comment: Yes closetnoc (the same). I've had a very confident steer on this I'm beginning to question. Answer edited. There are differences between what's reported in GA despite being sourced from SC.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Because Search Analytics do not filter the data whether you logged-in or not ( but data (positions) might change based on whether you logged-in or not, if aim not wrong). If you use custom search it will not reflect in Search-Analytics. But in Google Analytics you come to know if you configure to know the custom-search-analytics.  Search Analytics is the data from Google-Search-Engines only, I believe.