# Avoiding distortion of Google Search impressions

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-results, ranking

I'm primarily a software and web developer, but a client asked for SEO help with his low-traffic site. So, using Google Search, I could see their ranking for various search terms. But, doing so will distort impressions reports from Google Search Console.

How can I avoid this? Any way besides using a third-party search SERP tool? Maybe even using such a tool would distort things?

(I mention 'low-traffic', because presumably for a busier site my small number of Google search impressions would be a negligible drop in the bucket.)

**Edit**: There doesn't appear to be a way to get SERPs for a specific search phrase, except to try the search yourself, or have a third-party do so for you. You might think Google Search Console would, but, so far as can tell, it doesn't.

Comment: Simple answer: don't search for things just to check out rankings.

Comment: Also (though perhaps this should be an edit to the original) did find two earlier questions that are the same or similar to this one. Neither got a clear answer.
(https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101193/use-sitemysite-com-search-without-adding-impressions-to-google-search-console)
(https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101239/is-my-personal-search-considered-in-the-google-search-console)

Comment: As @LorenRosen has cited above, I asked a similar question. 'Negligible' -> A search in Google search bar using site:smallorbigsite.com can add a big spike of impressions distorting the data completely. Am hoping it's going to be addressed in the 'new' console.

Comment: You can whitelist your IP so that the impressions are not calculated?

Comment: That's the thing -- there doesn't appear to be such a whitelist, at least not that I noticed. Keep on hoping I overlooked something.